# Scale Website linearly and center elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question about scaling a website linearly.
I want the website or more specifically a DIV in which some elements are centered in to
scale down proportionally...

The HTML is:

```
<div id="header">Some Content with naviagtion</div>
<div id="slider">This Div should be scaled down...
   <img src="some images that are centered in the content Div"
</div>
```

So I tried this CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1919px) {
    #slider{position:fixed;top:0px !important;bottom:0px !important;transform: scale(.75);-webkit-transform: scale(.75);-moz-transform: scale(.75);-ms-transform: scale(.75);-o-transform: scale(.75);width: 200% !important;height: 200% !important;margin-top:-30% !important;margin-left:-50% !important; }
}
```

which works, but I have to set manual margins for all different resolutions...

So I want to scale down the whole `#slider` div that it fits to the screen so that top , left, right and bottom are 0 ... and the div is scaled down So everything is viewable also on little screens ... (some images are Full-HD ...)

Is there any way to make this automatically? Maybe with jQuery?

Best regards
Dave

Comment: do you want it to scale down in regards to the width ? is image suppose to be smaller or total div's width at maximum or all time, ... ? it is not clear to me

Comment: The whole DIV should be scaled down, not only the images ... so that everything is centered and the div fills out the whole screen

Comment: I have updated the description.. I hope it is clearer now?

Comment: heu, yes, did you try something like max-width:XX%; to scale down image ?

Comment: Hey . yes I tried this but the images are automatically centered from the slider plugin and if I only scale the images they not in the center anymore...

Comment: Could you give us a link or some code to work with? I'm having trouble visualizing what you need. Is the carousel in a div that scales?

Comment: yes thats basically the key:

the site is: http://hoellen.de